# Can't get a variabel to work in CommandText statement getting errorIncorrect syntax near '@P1'

Tags: sql, parameters, asp-classic

I am having to parmeterize an old classic ASP program to eliminate SQL injection.  The program allows the user to choose several options to search the database. It builds the user selections into a string which looks like the select line below.  The bolded part is the qry_str that is built by the program and then inserted in the commandtext by the parameter.  The problem is when I check the commandtext it looks like the second select statement and I get the error Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
select * from vw_results_2 where 0=0 **and tn_id=0.003001** 

select * from vw_results_2 where 0=0 **?**  

if serial_number <> "" then
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND TN_ID = "&serial_number
end if
if base <> "" then
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND BASE_ID = "&base
end if
if engineer <> "" then 
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND POC_USERID = '"&engineer&"'"
end if
if damage_area <> "" then 
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND DAMAGE_NOUN_ID = &damage_area
end if
if part_number <> "" then
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND PART_NUMBER LIKE '%"&part_number&"%'"
end if

set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = tadsdb
    cmd.CommandText = sortorder("SELECT * FROM VW_RESULTS_2 WHERE 0=0 ? ORDER BY ")
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@parm1",adVarChar,adParamInput,50,qry_str)
```

Comment: you create a parameter for cmd, but the CommandText does not seem to have a parameter. Or am I missing something

Comment: do you have an include file that defines adVarChar and adParamInput?

Comment: Yes I have the adovbs.inc file as an include statement.  In classic asp the ? is where the parameter is suppose to by the variable. and it doesn't put it for some reason.  for some reason part of my post got removed.  When I create the select statement and I check the commandtext it looks like this "Select * from table where 0=0 ?" instead it should look like this "select * from table where 0=0 and id = 12345"  Don't know why the ? not being replace with "and id - 12345"

Comment: You can’t use a parameterised query to add custom content like that. When you define a parameter and type adodb passes this information to RMDBS provider that then generates the sanitized SQL based on type passed. Here you specify the parameter so your SQL will generate as a string and you end up with something like `SELECT * FROM VW_RESULTS_2 WHERE 0=0 ' AND TN_ID = 12345' ORDER BY ` *(note the string characters `'` added to the SQL string)*.

Comment: To do what you are attempting you would need to build up the string as normal but use parameterised placeholders *(`?`)* in each conditional string you build, while also building the parameters at the same time so they build in order matching the required data type.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of parameterization is to separate *code* from *data*. If you could place code in a parameter and have it treated as code, you'd just be *moving* the place where SQL injection is possible.

One way of dealing with this (not ideal but not unreasonable until performance is demonstrably impacted, due to positional parameters) is to write your query like this:

```
select * from vw_results_2 where
   TN_ID = COALESCE(?,TN_ID) and
   BASE_ID = COALESCE(?,BASE_ID) AND ...
```

Then make your conditional logic decide whether it's going to supply a *value* for each parameter or to set it to `NULL` (so that the `COALESCE` skips that and uses the column value instead).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the whole answer, but you're missing a quote...

```
if damage_area <> "" then 
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND DAMAGE_NOUN_ID = &damage_area
end if
```

should be

```
if damage_area <> "" then 
  qry_str = qry_str&" AND DAMAGE_NOUN_ID = " &damage_area
end if
```